# How to pivot (transpose) data sets of differing length

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have 5000+ records in Column A. Each record contains a number of rows of data. The number of rows containing data varies from record to record. How do I transpose the data in these records so that each record occupies only one row? See included image. (using Excel included in Microsoft 365)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLAUr.png)

Comment: Hi @Sean Dalton,, now check the Edited part of my post,, it solves the issue, using MACRO the fastest way to works. Also,, if the suggested method works for you, then you may [accept it as answer](https://superuser.com/tour) as well Up vote ☺

Answer (score 1):

*Combination of `IFERROR & INDEX` command, and few helper value solves the issue.*

**::Caveat::**

- Shown method works with any version of Excel.
- It's not an smart method but solves the issue.
- To improvise this exercise, readers may suggest 
  an efficient Formula/Macro.

---

[image]

**How it works:**

**1.** Insert series of numbers (`I93:M93`) based on maximum elements per record set, here maximum is `5`.

**2.** Enter another series of numbers (`H94:H96`) based on record set, here are `3`.

**3.** Formula in cell `I94`:

```
 =IF($H94=1,IFERROR(INDEX($I$78:$I$82,I$93,1),""),IF($H94=2,IFERROR(INDEX($I$84:$I$86,I$93,1),""),IF($H94=3,IFERROR(INDEX($I$88:$I$92,I$93,1),""),"")))
```

**4,** Fill it across.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

---

**::Edited::**

*Since OP is handling huge data set (around 5000 records) therefore VBA Macro can a smart way to handle the issue.*

```
Sub TransposeWithBlanks()
 Dim Data_Array
 Dim OutPut_Array()
 Dim LR As Long, Counter As Long, LR2 As Long
 Dim i As Long

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  With Sheets("Sheet1")
     LR = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
     Data_Array = .Range("A1:A" & LR).Value2
  End With


    On Error Resume Next
    For i = LBound(Data_Array, 1) To UBound(Data_Array, 1)

       If Trim(Data_Array(i, 1)) <> vbNullString Then
            Counter = Counter + 1

            ReDim Preserve OutPut_Array(1 To 1, 1 To Counter)

            OutPut_Array(1, Counter) = Data_Array(i, 1)

        Else

            With Sheets("Sheet1")
                LR2 = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
                .Range("C" & LR2 + 1).Resize(1, Counter).Value2 = OutPut_Array
            End With

            Counter = 0
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

---

[image]

**N.B.**

- **S**ave the workbook as **M**acro Enabled.
- In Above code Sheet name and data range are editable.
- If you want to **P**aste the Transposed data in another Sheet, then you need to edit this portion of the code.

  ```
  With Sheets("Sheet1")
              LR2 = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
              .Range("C" & LR2 + 1).Resize(1, Counter).Value2 = OutPut_Array
          End With
  ```

Answer (score 0):

that is very kind of you to look at this challenge. While your formula works, it expects to be told the cell range for each individual record ($I$84:$I$86 for Record 2...then $I$88:$I$92 for Record 3... and so on. With 5000 records, one would need to input the ranges of each of the 5000 individual records - which is not really practical.

I am not an excel guru, so please excuse my following 'layman's' thoughts.

The formula (or more likely macro?) that I think would work is as follows (using your table above):
1) Instruct the macro to search downwards in column I for the word (string?) "Record".
2) Each time the macro finds the word "Record" instruct it to copy/paste the data in the subsequent cells immediately below, horizontally into the adjacent cells (to its right) - and stop the copy/paste when it reaches the next cell down with another word "record".

As I said, I don't know how to 'program' formulas or macros in excel - so my suggestion may be totally not possible.

Anyhow, regardless, you have been very kind to look at this. I hope someone has come across this problem before, and has a workable answer.

Yours kindly, Sean

Comment: I think you have crated duplicate account [Check this help merge both](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts). Also what you have posted as answer should be COMMENT,, so please [edit] your post and add the solution/method, if it deffer from other answers. Also modify the question, add that U need a Macro based solution, and add new TAG `Vba` .

Comment: Hi Rajesh - thank you again. I will try your new suggestion, and fix up my account/comment etc. I'll circle back once I have tried macro. Thank you again for your great work! Sean

Comment: Hi Rajesh, your VBA Macro worked a treat. Well done and thank you very much! I have also requested my accounts be merged. Not sure how I got 2?

Comment: Glad to help you ,,, since VBA is working then you may accept my post as Answer as well up vote too [Check this](https://superuser.com/tour) ☺

Comment: Hi Rajesh, I gave 2 votes. I hope these have been reflected. I am struggling a bit to navigate the Super User UI... :-(

Comment: On top left of my post is grey tick ,, just click it to accept as answer,,, but It's okay ,,, keep asking ☺